# Formatting with par, better padding

Tags: formatting

I've started using

`set formatprg=par\ 66q\ g1\ j " keep double spaces, justify`

which makes beautifully justified paragraphs.  But it would be better if the algorithm preferred to pad after .:;, in that order.  Perhaps some such algo. exists?

Comment: The answer should be obvious from Par's [manual](http://www.nicemice.net/par/par-doc.var)... provided that you're one of the three persons alive that actually understand said manual. :) Unrelated: don't put comments at end of lines in Vim files, especially to `set` lines.

Comment: @SatoKatsura, are you saying that this posibility already lies in par? why not put comments there? had no problem with it so far.

Comment: Re: comments at end of lines: `"` is also a string delimiter, Vim's parser is not particularly robust, and the syntax of `set` is not exactly straightforward.  Sooner or later you'll get comments parsed as option values.  This is a well-known pitfall.